# Gnome- vs Unity-panel (applet) compatibility?

Tags: gnome-panel, indicator, compatibility

I just love the indicator-applet and other parts of the Ayatana-project and think Ubuntu has done an awesome job there. And as the question about applet compatibility seem to be answered as a 'no' I'd like to take the question to the next level - the 'why' and 'why not'.

How come these Ayatana-applets today work in gnome-panel but gnome applets won't work in the Unity panel?

And - as it's connected - why not make them compatible? Isn't it all about usability?

Answer (score 7):

Many of the gnome-applets you are familiar with use old technologies like Bonobo, etc. To bring them up to a modern standard, they would need to be rethought/rewritten/etc from scratch using newer technologies such as D-BUS.

Making the applets compatible will not improve **usability** but just backwards compatibility. Furthermore, "Ayatana-applets" as you call them, are not "applets" in the sense you might be thinking, but are **indicators** ([see here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators)). With the amount of work that would be required for bringing the old applets into new technology would be rather pointless (*to quote the Bible indirectly, it's like putting new wine in old wine skins*), [since GNOME 3 will be basically make these obsolete](http://live.gnome.org/ThreePointZero).

*It would also be of note that GNOME Shell will not support these old applets either.*

Comment: Hmm, then is GNOME 3 going to use the same architecture as Unity's panel?

Comment: No, for some reason, the (arrogant) GNOME developers rejected indicator applets, then proceeded to practically remake the technology in gnome shell -_